# PHP веб сокеты для Streaming Api Vk

Tags: php, сокет, websocket, vk-streaming-api

Здравствуйте, относительно недавно у Вконтакте появился Streaming API, и тем по нему мало, я решил написать сайт для дианона личности, написал интересный алгоритм распознавания города жертвы исходя из городов друзей и групп, обучил нейронную сеть и просто начал скребсти данные. Но вот потом вспомнил про `Streaming API`. Нужно извлечь данные из web-socket.

---

Для передачи данных используется протокол WebSocket. В заголовке запроса нужно передать ключи, необходимые для обновления соединения до WebSocket:

```
“Connection: upgrade” 
“Upgrade: websocket” 
“Sec-Websocket-Version: 13”
```

---

Вот что написано в документации.

**Вопросы**

1. Как выполнить то действие (передать в заголовок).
2. Как считывать данные из потока

Answer (score 0):

Для начала читать данные лучше через написанный сервис (например на Node JS, сам PHP, к сожалению, мало подходит для этих целей).

Используйте готовые библиотеки ws, socket.io и т.д. Обычно при соединении они сами добавляют соответствующие заголовки, но в случае необходимости вы можете передать их в параметрах options при создании нового соединения.